# Intuitive notion of negation: implication example

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am bit puzzled with intuitive notion of negating an implication.
Say we have an implication.
If A is true, then B is true.
Say we want to negate it. Not analytically, rather intuitively.

Now, why is following **NOT** a negation of implication?

> If A is true, then B is either true or not (we don't know).

Comment: What you have written is a tautology. '$B$ is either true or not' is a tautology because $B$ has to be either true or false, so the statement is always true. Logically, $B\oplus\neg B=B+(\neg B)=1$. This means you are proposing $A\to1\equiv1$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri consider *if A is true then B is sometimes true sometimes false*, I know this kind of things might not be studied in logic, but I am trying to illustrate what I meant. That maybe negation is not only when A is true and B is false, but maybe if A is true and you don't know status of B that is also negation.

Comment: How exactly do you define _'sometimes'_? More formally, do you mean to say there is a third (or more) variable(s), say $C$, that controls the state of $B$ other than $A$?

Comment: "We don't know" is open whereas in fact it is either true/false or inconsistent, or can't be known....each has its own treatement

Comment: @davidk I think you are misinterpreting negation. $\neg(A\to B)$ is _defined_ to be true _whenever_ $A\to B$ is false  and vice-versa. The trueness of the statement dictates the trueness of its negation. Stating $A\to B$ locks the trueness of the statement $\neg(A\to B)$ for all the possible true-false combinations for $A,B$, leaving no room for the uncertainty 'we don't know'.

Answer (score 1):

The *conditional* $A \to B$ does not mean :

> "If A is true, then B is true".

The truth table for the conditional has four cases, and only one of them has FALSE as "output".

Thus, considering the negation of $A \to B$, we want that it is TRUE exactly when the original one is FALSE.

I.e. $\lnot (A \to B)$ must be TRUE exactly when $A$ is TRUE and $B$ is FALSE.

This means that the negation of "If A is true, then B is true" is equivalent to :

> "A and **not** B".

---

Another approach is : consider that $A \to B$ is TRUE either when $A$ is FALSE, or when $A$ is TRUE also $B$ is.

---

There are many discussion about the use of *conditional* in natural languages and its counterpart in logic; see e.g. the so-called [Paradoxes of material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxes_of_material_implication).

The [Material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) of classical propositional calculus is **defined** through its truth table and thus it is a "simplified model" of the way natural language works.

Its usefulness in formalizing many mathematical (and not only) arguments is the only reason to use it in formal contexts.

---

---

Quite different is the case when "implication" means [Logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence).

We have that $A \vDash B$ when there is no interpretations that makes $A$ True and $B$ False.

In this case, we have that if $A$ is True, we can assert that also $B$ is.

On the other hand, if $A$ is False, then $B$ can be either True or False.

If we follow this approach, what is the negation of $A \vDash B$ ?

It is :

> there is at least one interpretation that makes $A$ True and $B$ False.

Comment: You answered analytically again, mine was maybe more philosophical in nature, why is: "If A is true, then B is either true or not (we don't know)." NOT a negation of implication, on a intuitive level, because it seems it *could* be.

Comment: Very good points made here. Thank you.

Comment: The so-called paradoxes of material implications are the inevitable consequence of simple, self-evident rules of natural deduction: 1. Conditional proof ($\implies$ intro), 2. Proof by contradiction ($\neg$ intro), 3. Join statements ($\land$ Intro), 4. Split statements ($\land$ elim), 5. Double Negation ($\neg \neg$ elim).

Answer (score 0):

What does $A$ implies $B$ mean in classical logic? In the context of a logical proof, it means only that, *at the moment*, it is *not* the case that both A is true and B is false. Symbolically:

> $A \implies B \space \equiv \space \neg (A \land \neg B)$

This is often given as a definition in textbooks, but it can also be derived using other rules of natural deduction including other elementary properties of logical implication.

Note that there is no suggestion here of cause and effect, or the passage of time. It may help to think of it is as a single snap shot of reality. This is true of classical logic in general, and nearly all of modern mathematics. For the most part, causality and the passage of time are in the realms of science, not mathematics.

Now, the negation of $A\implies B$ is obviously $A\land \neg B$.

In words: $A$ is true and $B$ is false.